# AngularJS code impact analysis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, trace, impact-analysis

How would one perform code change impact analysis on an AngularJS website?
So if I have modified a block of code, is there anyway to determine what features are affected by this change?

Comment: You mean like, you change a variable name, and it would tell you "Hey, you changed this variable which also appears here here here and here"?

Comment: yes, but also what functions are affected if i change this function.

Comment: It seems to be a wrong point of view. Usually you don't need a hindsight. What you need is 'refactoring' functionality, it is the essential feature of any advanced IDE (e.g. Jetbrains').

Comment: @estus that doesn't really make sense .... profiling and stack traces are very helpful to know what to refactor

Comment: @charlietfl They are very helpful but they are off the topic. The question is about specific code modification, there's no mention of 'what to refactor'.